# Can't receive data of the HC - 05 after successful connection on my android studio app

Tags: java, android, arduino

I have used BluetoothSPP Library:

https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary

The arduino connecting successfully to the android studio application, but I can't receive the data, I will import both of my codes and please some one tell me if I did something wrong, from what I read and understood , bluetooth.setOnDataReceivedListener is the function to receive and you should place bluetooth.print(data) on the arduino part in order to

Android:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
final String ON = "1";
final String OFF = "0";
BluetoothSocket socket;

private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
BluetoothSPP bluetooth;
private BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;
TextView text;
private BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
String TAG = "TEST: ";
Button connect;
Button on;
Button off;
private OnDataReceivedListener mDataReceivedListener = null;



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            bluetooth.connect(data);
    } else if (requestCode == BluetoothState.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            bluetooth.setupService();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    , "Bluetooth was not enabled."
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}


public void setOnDataReceivedListener (OnDataReceivedListener listener) {
    if (mDataReceivedListener == null)
        mDataReceivedListener = listener;
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!bluetooth.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
        bluetooth.enable();
    } else {
        if (!bluetooth.isServiceAvailable()) {
            bluetooth.setupService();
            bluetooth.startService(BluetoothState.DEVICE_OTHER);
        }
    }
}

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bluetooth = new BluetoothSPP(this);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.on);
    off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.off);
    BluetoothSocket socket = null;

    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (!bluetooth.isBluetoothAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
        bluetooth.setOnDataReceivedListener(new BluetoothSPP.OnDataReceivedListener() {
            public void onDataReceived(byte[] data, String message) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Start Reading");
                /*Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                Log.i("Check", "Message : " + message);
            }
        });

        bluetooth.setBluetoothConnectionListener(new BluetoothSPP.BluetoothConnectionListener() {
        public void onDeviceConnected(String name, String address) {
            connect.setText("Connected to " + name);
        }

        public void onDeviceDisconnected() {
            connect.setText("Connection lost");
        }

        public void onDeviceConnectionFailed() {
            connect.setText("Unable to connect");
        }
    });

    connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (bluetooth.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                bluetooth.disconnect();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceList.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
            }


        }
    });


    on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Its on");
            bluetooth.send(ON, true);



        }


    });

    off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Its off");
            bluetooth.send(OFF, true);
        }
    });





}
```

arduino part:

[image]

Comment: `android-studio` tag should be used only for IDE-specific problems.

Comment: Have you configured the hc-05 module to communicate using 38400 baud rate?

Comment: No , do you mean from the AT commands?

Comment: I thought putting the baud rate in the code means configuring it but seems that am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino code looks right.
Try first a Bluetooth serial monitor on your Android to check if the data is really being sent and received.
Then make sure in your Android code you connect to the module first then try to receive the data.

Comment: I have tried that I receive random HEX values not what I see on the serial monitor.

Comment: Try to change the baudrate of the bluetooth terminal and see if you can see the data.